# socketfilterfw and repeating error messages

Tags: firewall

Every two seconds I get the following messages via Console:

```
Standard    13:47:41.404793 +0100   socketfilterfw  MacOS error: -67065
Standard    13:47:41.405321 +0100   socketfilterfw  UNIX error exception: 3
Standard    13:47:43.393518 +0100   socketfilterfw  MacOS error: -67065
Standard    13:47:43.393927 +0100   socketfilterfw  UNIX error exception: 3
```

And they keep on and on.  Turning off the firewall, they disappear, of course.  Now I wasn't able to find the meaning of the mentioned error codes.  Does anybody know what goes wrong here?

Comment: Just a general note, the logging subsystem can safely log millions of events a day, so other than learning - there may not be any practical problem here that doesn’t get solved by search / filtering the entries. To see your count of logged messages, from a shell run `log stats`

Answer (score 2):

The program causing the error is WiFiSpy, see here: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/wifi-spy/id541505649?mt=8

Comment: Perhaps this was the answer for you, congrats. I have never downloaded or used the WiFiSpy app. I am seeing the same messages in my logs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the OP's own answer, I've also eliminated this error, however in my case it was WiFi Signal by [Intuitbits.com](https://www.intuitibits.com/products/) available on the AppStore.

There is a 100% correlation between this app being open and the same error messages appearing roughly every second. It seems there is a more general issue with polling socketfilterfw, but with High Sierra being an obsolete OS I can't foresee a solution other than not using such apps except when needed for a short time,

This under High Sierra (10.13.6) and Wifi Signal 4.4.5 (updated April 2022).

I shall, of course, be filing a bug report with the developer.

Comment: I should add that error code -67065  signifies "host has no guest with the requested attributes" according to this list of error codes hosted on [George Garside's blog](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/macos-security-error-codes/). 

I'm guessing that these WiFi monitoring apps poll for dummy WiFi clients in order to gain the information they require to function. If this is correct, then generating error codes in the log is an unavoidable consequence of how they work.

Hopefully this will help others such as @SunSpark track down the app causing them issues.